# How do I restrict the domain over which an equation is solved?

Tags: equation-solving, warning-messages

I tried to use the `Solve` function to find all solutions to $\sin x = \cos(2x)$ in the interval `[0, 2π)`.

I evaluated

```
Solve[Sin[x] == Cos[2 x], {x, 0, 2π}]
```

but it gives the error message

> Solve::ivar: 0 is not a valid variable.

I am a newb and I have little to no knowledge of the program.

Comment: Before asking a question you should look into documentation pages. Try  `Solve[Sin[x] == Cos[2 x] && 0 <= x <= 2 Pi, x]`. This question is too basic and should be closed.

Answer (score 1):

`Solve`'s 2nd argument must be a variable or list of variables to solve for. It takes conditions restricting those variables as part of its 1st argument. So you should write

```
Solve[Sin[x] == Cos[2 x] && 0 ≤ x ≤ 2 π, x]
```

which will give

> ```
> {{x -> π/6}, {x -> (5 π)/6}, {x -> (3 π)/2}, {x -> (3 π)/2}}
> ```

You can visually verify the solution by making a plot. Like so:

```
Plot[{Sin[x], Cos[2 x]}, {x, 0, 2 π},
  Ticks -> {(π/6) Range[0, 12], Automatic}]]
```

[image: plot]